# enable / disable textbox depending on checkbox - javascript

Tags: javascript, php

hi i have some problem when i try to make some php with javascript function
what i want to make is a textbox that will go enable / disable depending on checkbox on left side

this is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function enable_txtbox(id){
            if(document.getElementById(id).disabled){
                document.getElementById(id).disabled=false;
                var x = document.getElementById(id).disabled;
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
            }
            else
                document.getElementById(id).disabled=true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Nama Gejala</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nama"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenis Gejala</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><select name="jenis">
                        <option value="0">Umum</option>
                        <option value="1">Khusus</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Penyakit yang Berhubungan</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                </tr>  
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                    $id=1;
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                        $id=$row['id'];
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='chk$id' value='$id' onclick='enable_txtbox('".$id."')'>".$row['nama']."<br></td>";
                        echo "<td>Nilai Kepastian</td>";
                        echo"<td>:</td>";
                        echo "<td><input type='text' name='cf".$id." id='$id' disabled='disabled'></td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    mysqli_close($con);
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <p id="demo"></p>
                    <td><input type="submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PS : i have more than 1 checkboxes and textboxes depending on my database file

thanks before and forgive me for my bad english skill :)

Comment: Change `disabled` to `checked`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem.

Script...

```
    function enable_txtbox(id){
        if(document.getElementById(id).disabled){
            document.getElementById(id).disabled=false;
            var x = document.getElementById(id).disabled;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
        } else {                
            document.getElementById(id).disabled=true;
            var x = document.getElementById(id).disabled;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
        }
    }
```

HTML....

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Nama Gejala</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nama"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenis Gejala</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><select name="jenis">
                        <option value="0">Umum</option>
                        <option value="1">Khusus</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Penyakit yang Berhubungan</td>
                <td>:</td>
            </tr>   
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>check1</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="enable_txtbox('first')" /></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Txt1</td>
                <td><textarea id="first"> </textarea></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>check2</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="enable_txtbox('second')" /></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Txt2</td>
                <td><textarea id="second"> </textarea></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <p id="demo"></p>
                <td><input type="submit"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[JSPIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bhimubgm/U8zxR/)

Comment: well since my checkbox and my textbox is depending on my database, i don't think your html is right

Comment: I hope each row $id is unique. If I'm right you just have to pass $id to your js method and use the same $id as respective textarea. Make sure what  you are getting in js as id is same as your textarea id.

Comment: $id is unique because that is my database's id field
i don't know what the reason, but my js function not working on my code, even for only call my function is not work

Comment: Have you checked browser console for errors?
Try using just `disabled` instead of `disabled='disabled'`

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery to check whether the checkbox is checked.
Say you have a checkbox with id='idTag', and we would like to check whether the checkbox is checked or not.

```
$('#idTag').is(":checked")
```

This returns true should the Checkbox be checked; from that moment on you could use jQuery to either show the  were it hidden, or append it to the div.
say the text input box has id 'textId'.

Method one:

```
if($('#idTag').is(":checked"))
    $("#textId").css("display", "block"); //if you just like to show the block.

if($('#idTag').is(":checked"))
    $("#textId").fadeIn("slow"); //Gives it a nice effect as well.
```

Method two:

```
<div id='DIV'>
   <input type='checkbox' id='idTag' value='checkbox'/>
</div>
<script>
   if($('#idTag').is(":checked"))
       $("#DIV").append("<input type='text' placeholder='textbox' />");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your function

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/x8dSP/2853/

```
<script>
    function enable_txtbox(id){
    if(document.getElementById(id).disabled == true){
        document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: i have seen your code on that link, but it still not work on mine
i think my problem is on my checkbox declaration that on echo statement